# How do I change timezone in mysql in 'default' and 'on update' current_timestamp only?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently struggling on to insert default value to the table.

I just want to insert default datetime value to 'created_at', and default 'on update' to 'updated_at' column. But because schema's timezone is different, so when I change column it only shows UTC time.

```
alter table table1
    change created_at created_at datetime not null default date_add(current_timestamp, interval 9 hour);

alter table table1
    change updated_at updated_at datetime not NULL default current_timestamp on update date_add(current_timestamp, interval 9 hour);
```

So I tried this but it doesn't work. I found this answer: [MySQL set default value for DATE column using DATE_ADD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942977/mysql-set-default-value-for-date-column-using-date-add)

So I understood what the problem is, but I just want to make sure I have to save created_at and updated_at based on UTC + 9 hours not changing default timezone. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
Scroll down to the [mysqld] section, and find the default-time-zone = "+00:00" line. Change the +00:00 value (the GMT value) to +09:00 (the time zone you want). Save the file and exit.

if not found add `default-time-zone = "+09:00"`

then restart the mysql
`sudo service mysql restart`

Another option to use query
`sudo mysql -e "SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+9:00';"`
then check with `sudo mysql -e "SELECT @@global.time_zone;"`

Comment: No, I just don't want to change mysql timezone setting. because other tables do not follow +09:00 timezones...

Comment: I only want to make one column's 'default' to follow specific timezone...

Answer (score 0):

```
Setting time_zone in my.cnf options file ( In MySQL:8.0.26 and CentOS 7 )

sudo vi /etc/my.cnf

And add this line: ( I have set the timezone as per India - Asia/Kolkata )
default-time-zone = "+5:30"

Then save the file and restart MySQL server
sudo systemctl restart mysqld

Then check the MySQL server status
sudo systemctl status mysqld
```